# TypeError: forward() missing 1 required positional argument in a method

Tags: python, pytorch, torch

I use the following model:

> ```
> model = DeepGraphInfomax(128, pos_summary_t).to(device)
> ```

which looks like:

> class DeepGraphInfomax(torch.nn.Module):
>
> ```
> def __init__(self, hidden_channels, pos_summary):#, encoder):#, summary, corruption):
>     super().__init__()
>     self.hidden_channels = hidden_channels
>     #self.encoder = GCNEncoder() # needs to be defined either here or give it to here (my comment)
>     self.pos_summary = pos_summary
>     #self.corruption = corruption
>
>     self.weight = Parameter(torch.Tensor(hidden_channels, hidden_channels))
>
>     #self.reset_parameters()
>
>
>
>
> def forward(self, pos_summary, *args, **kwargs):
>   
>     #pos_z = self.encoder(*args, **kwargs)
>     #cor = self.corruption(*args, **kwargs)
>     #cor = cor if isinstance(cor, tuple) else (cor, )
>     #neg_z = self.encoder(*cor)
>     summary = self.summary(pos_summary, *args, **kwargs)
>     return summary# pos_z#, neg_z, summary
> ```

but running model() gives me the error:

> TypeError: forward() missing 1 required positional argument:
> 'pos_summary'

Comment: While instantiating ```DeepGraphInfomax```, ```__init__``` is expecting another parameter ```pos_summary```; but you are not providing it.

Comment: I define pos_summary before as a vector.

Comment: or do you mean something else?

Answer (score 2):

`model` is an object since you instantiated `DeepGraphInfomax`.
`model()` calls the `.__call__` function.
`forward` is called in the `.__call__` function i.e. `model()`.
Have a look at [here](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/any-different-between-model-input-and-model-forward-input/3690).
The `TypeError` means that you should write input in forward function i.e.  `model(data)`.

Here is an exmaple:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

class example(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.mlp = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(5,2), nn.ReLU(), nn.Linear(2,1), nn.Sigmoid())

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.mlp(x)

# instantiate object
test = example()

input_data = torch.tensor([1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0])

# () and forward() are equal
print(test(input_data)) 
print(test.forward(input_data))

# outputs for me
#(tensor([0.5387], grad_fn=<SigmoidBackward>),
# tensor([0.5387], grad_fn=<SigmoidBackward>))
```

Comment: yes, i understand that: but your last sentence is unclear to me:
"The TypeError means that you should write input in forward function i.e. model(data)." so i should write model(data) as a positional argument in my forward function?

Comment: You should write the "positional argument" in your forward function. The type error means that you miss the input of the forward function.

Comment: Could you make an example please

Comment: I added an example.

Comment: I got it now....